# Modify JSON string in SQL (datetime entry)

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
| Id        | Data     | TimeStamp                                                         
-- Example info. Check Data EOL to see Time
| Id        | 732DC7DE-2B9D-4B91-8753-0004128B26D2 
| Data      | {"message":"Machine is down","machineId":"165ACE37-4E2C-4D44-9D14-D4D3ABK66C","machineName":"1501","ipAddress":"192.168.0.1","time":"2018-05-20T18:33:23.171"} 
| TimeStamp | 2018-05-20 18:33:23.1710000
```

I need to convert the datetime values in this table to `UTC` time.

I've figured out the TimeStamp conversion.

`Update ProcessEventMessage SET TimeStamp = DateADD(hour, -2, TimeStamp)`

*My local is `UTC+2h`* I.E. I have to remove 2h from the json-data.

But I have no idea how to convert the `json-datetime` object into `UTC`. 
I've tried something like this but without success. How would I accomplish converting these numbers into `UTC`? (i.e. remove two hours).

```
"time":"2018-05-20T18:33:23.171"
```

[Read more about ISO_8601 Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)  Structure: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSS

**TL;DR: Remove 2h from the json string**

Thoughts: one way to do this, would be to look for the **T** in the time, and replace the hours after it to deduct 2h. (possible?)

EDIT:

I've now got a structured query of the sql-table like this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = {"message":"Machine is down","machineId":"165ACE37-4E2C-4D44-9D14-F9E2CB2C2C13","machineName":"1501","ipAddress":"192.168.150.101","time":"2018-05-20T18:33:23.171"}
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH (  message varchar(200) '$.message',
    machineId varchar(200) '$.machineId',
    machineName int '$.machineName',
    ipAddress varchar(200) '$.ipAddress',
    time datetime2(7) '$.time'
)
```

Can i somehow use these variables to modify the value?

Comment: Why don't you use [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and avoid any assumptions about UTC or offsets? The offset for *your server* will change when summer time ends. The offset *for your source* will change, probably at a different date.

Comment: And no, the functions you used are *wrong* for datetime conversion. What are you going to do when summer time ends? If you want to work with offsets, the appropriate functions are [SWITCHOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/switchoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [TODATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/todatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, let me give you more context: The reason for doing these conversions is so that we can change the time on the server to UTC, but the timestamps currently in there are UTC+2. Hence why i need to deduct 2h. 
However, what time i'm converting to is hardly the pressing issue here. I need to edit time from the json-data field, that's what i'm struggeling with.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @UTCDateTime DATETIME = GETUTCDATE();

SET @UTCDateTime = TimeStamp AT TIME ZONE 'your time zone' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
SET @UTCDateTime = TimeStamp AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'

select @UTCDateTime
```

(`AT TIME ZONE`) works on only SQL Server 2016+

Comment: What about the JSON data that has to be converted?

Comment: @Joel you asked about converting time. Putting the converted time into JSON or a table field is a different matter. Besides, if you wanted to manipulate a JSON string, why do it in the *database*?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, not really no. Selective reading is dangerous sometimes. You could split the question down into these parts: 1) I want to modify the json string, 2) the sub-string that i want to modify contains DateTime information, 3) i want to remove 2h from it.

Comment: You can modify JSON string with JSON_MODIFY function, but you have to pass the index to the function. SET @JSON = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON, '$.JsonObject[0].A', 'something'). Also, try with OPENJSON function.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @JSON = 
'{
"TMP": [    
    {"message":"Machine is down","machineId":"165ACE37-4E2C-4D44-9D14-F9E2CB2C2C13","machineName":"1501","ipAddress":"192.168.150.101","time":"2018-05-20T18:33:23.171"}]}
'
SET @JSON = JSON_MODIFY(@JSON, '$.TMP[0]', 'something')
```